# Update object mapped to string using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I am using `ObjectMapper` to map my Object to the json string using the following code. Then adding this to an array. How can I update the already added object? I have a unique id for the object. Now it is added as a new entry in the array.

```
final JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
while(){
    //some code here
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jString;                 
    try {
        jString = mapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);
        jArray.add(jString);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Example,
In the array myobject is

```
["{\"id\":\"25641\",\"name\":abc.....
```

now if the name changes and I have to update it. When I add the object, it is getting duplicated like,

```
["{\"id\":\"25641\",\"name\":abc.....
["{\"id\":\"25641\",\"name\":pqr.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not store objects in a plain array or a collection? Then when you need to do some modification just update the object in the array/collection and recreate whole JSONArray (if you need it)

**Update** (thanks to [mibrahim.iti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5792859/mibrahim-iti)):

For example using

```
Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(500, objectOfId500);//this will replace old object with new one
map.values();//for retrieving all objects then using it in final mapping
```

So finally the method should be something like that:

```
Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
while(){
    map.put(myObject.getId(), myObject);
}
Collection<Object> coll = map.values(); // Final objects which will be converted to JSON Array
final JSONArray jArray = createJSONArray(coll);
```